# Nuxt - login without redirect

Tags: authentication, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to create authentication on my Nuxt app, but every tutorial I've found is using redirect to public / private paths.

Example:

```
if (user.isLoggedIn()) {
    redirect('/dashboard')
} else {
    redirect('/login')
}
```

I'm used to react way, where I have a single wrapper component in which I decide by the state if I want to show public (login) or private (dashboard) page.

Example of index page (route path '/'):

```
export default = ({ viewer }) =>
   viewer.isLoggedIn ? <Dashboard /> : <Login />
```

Is there any way to achieve this in Nuxt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set a dynamic `layout` parameter in your Page.vue files.

first step, set dynamic layout in your Page.vue:

```
export default {
  layout (context) {
    return context.isLoggedIn ? 'privateLayout' : 'publicLayout';
  }
}
```

second step, set a Context custom var (or better, in your Store) from a middleware auth:

```
export default function (context) {
   context.isLoggedIn = true; //or false, insert your auth checking here
}
```

see documentation: https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-layout#the-layout-property

see live example: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/nuxt-dynamic-layouts?path=pages/index.vue:10:8

Comment: Thanks, but probably my description of problem wasn't right. This will only change layout (router wrapper or shell). What I want to do is that user is on index page. If he is logged in, show login page on index, otherwise show dashboard page on index.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your index page as a wrapper for two components that show depending on whether the user is logged in. So inside your index.vue:

```
<template>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <dashboard v-if="userIsLoggedIn" />
    <login v-else />
  </div>
</template>
```

Then you could write the dashboard and login component as separate pages and even switch dynamically between them by making `userIsloggedIn` reactive.

Hope that's more like what you're looking for.